# Is it possible to create a pivot table from a data model that is in another excel workbook?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, datamodel

Basically, due to size of files, after creating the data model i would like to have the pivot tables in another workbook, but seems like data model pivot tables should be in the same workbook as the data model, is there any work around possible?

I tried using external data source but the connection to the data model does not appear. Also tried many keywords in google to learn it without asking.

Comment: how big is your data size?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The main files i am using have around 200 mb but data model file is only 16 mb.

Comment: It is possible, this approach is called "Using Excel as Thin Client for Power Pivot", for example see: https://powerpivotpro.com/2011/02/powerpivot-scheduled-refresh-pt-3-thin-workbooks/     However, I'd recommend against it - it's not a robust solution. Your data is not that big (I used gigabyte data without problems); if you insist, a much better solution is to setup Tabular server and use Excel with it.

Comment: Thanks Rado! I will see Tabular, probably will simplify and let the pivots  in the same sheet but for the future will know already other solutions ;) ty